# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'die' (T_EXIT) in line 14

Tags: php, html

hello im trying to follow login code but i always get the error of unexpected die , i saw almost all previous answers for this error but non of it helped me in my code

here is the the php code : [heres all the codes i'm following](http://hzonesp.com/php/login-using-salt-hash-password-logout-php-mysql/)

```
<?php
$usernameVal=$_REQUEST["username"];
//$passwordVAl=$_REQUEST["password"];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "learn2crack-login-register";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    $escapedPW = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST['password']);
```

what am i doing wrong ??

Comment: This is your actual code or a simplified version? Usually that error would be from not closing the line before. (Also when I run this code I dont get the notice)

Comment: noo just part of it , i'll edit my question and put the whole code @chris85

Comment: Just look at the preceding line, does it end with a semi-colon?

Comment: do you see the missing `}` at the very end??? I guess thats not the mistake but never no. was not able to reproduce the error on my server...

Comment: yes it does @chris85

Comment: Please add the first 14 lines, redact any credentials.

Comment: you can find it on your own - i bet!!! delete everything except the very first line. then step by step undelete each line until the error comes up

Comment: i have posted the tutorial i have followed , its in ( login_nextpage.php) inside the link @chris85

Comment: Might be some hidden character was copy/pasted. Try deleting the line or comment it out.

Comment: What is the exact error log? Post the whole line